# Pentaho Run SSH Commands Step - Publickey authentication failed

Tags: ssh, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to get "Run SSH Commands" step working in my local machine. I am able to SSH into a remote machine from the command line, but when I do the same with Pentaho, it returns the below error:

[image]

Does this step need any additional configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show your configuration?
let try to use User/pass and uncheck 'Use key'.
If you want connect using private key option without password config, you need key-gen and copy key to ssh server.